# Vertical align multiple objects in table cell

Tags: html, css

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Crystall/Mgwzx/).
How can I vertically center the `img` and `div` inside the `td`, without using of absolute values (i.e. **px**)?

Pure CSS solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you will have to set a width on the div, otherwise it will be pushed below the img

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mgwzx/10/

```
<div style="width:100%; height:60px; position:relative; overflow:visible;">
    <table style="width:400px; table-layout:fixed" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle; width:200px;">
                <img align="left" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/donate/c/c0/Information-icon.png" style="float:left;margin-top:50px;" />
                <div style="text-align:center; float:left; width:150px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to set any sizes, like `width:150px`. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe, but not really. Divs are meant to stretch to fill all available width unless you designate their width. This will cause long text within that div to first make the div stretch till its on a new line from the image, than till it fills the full width of the parent, and only then would the text line break. Perhaps what you want to achieve your desired layout is to nest another table within that table cell?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to setting the info icon as a background to the TD, I would try this:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bs2DY/)

```
td { 
  background: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/donate/c/c0/Information-icon.png') no-repeat left center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

We know that the width of the icon is 20px, so by setting the background image to no-repeat and applying a `padding-left: 20px` to the TD, it aligns it properly and doesn't overlap. And by setting background-position of `left center`, it'll alwyays remain vertically centered.